# Error: List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic> Future Builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to generate a FutureBuilder gridView but no matter what I do it keeps getting the error: List is not a subtype of type Map<String, dynamic>, I've tried most of the stack suggestions for those who had similar errors but none of them worked.

shop.dart

```
@freezed
class Shop with _$Shop {
  factory Shop({
    int? id,
    String? name,
    String? logo,
    Location? location,
  }) = _Location;
  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LocationFromJson(json);

  static Location fromJsonModel(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location.fromJson(json);
}
```

shop_service.dart

```
class ShopService extends BaseHttpService {
  final AppContext appContext;
  late String _shopApi;

  ShopService(http.Client client, this.appContext) : super(httpClient: client) {
    _shopApi = '${Globals.ApiEndpoint}/user/${appContext.currentCustomer.id}/shops/';
  }

   Future<List<Shop>> fetch() async {
    var token = await this.appContext.currentUser!.getIdToken();
    final response = await callApi(_shopApi, token); //response = response.body from http handler
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response); // also tried List jsonMap = json.decode(response).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    return jsonResponse.map((item) => new Shop.fromJson(item)).toList();
  }
}
```

shop_screen.dart

```
class _ShopTabScreenState extends State<ShopTabScreen> {
  late ShopService _shopService;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _shopService = svcContainer<shopService>();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
              child: InputField(
                obscureText: false,
                hintText: 'text',
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
            Text(
              'Participating Shop',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 5.0,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _shopService.fetch(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Shop>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final content = snapshot.data!;
                return gridViewBuild(content);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              }

              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
            // child: SizedBox(
            //   height: 100.0,
            //   child:
            // ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _refresh(String shopId) {
      setState(() {});
  }

  Widget gridViewBuild(List<Shop> data) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: new GridView.builder(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3, crossAxisSpacing: 10, childAspectRatio: (1 / 0.75), mainAxisSpacing: 10),
          itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            if (data[index].shop != null) {
              return new LocationYes(
                  shopImg: data[index].logo,
                  shopId: data[index].id.toString(),
                  shopName: data[index].name);
            } else {
              return new LocationdNo(
                  shopImg: data[index].logo,
                  shopId: data[index].id.toString(),
                  shopName: data[index].name);
                  newLocationCallback: _refresh);
            }
            return new Container();
          }),
    );
  }
}
}
```

Json Response

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1",
        "logo": "test1.png",
        "location": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "locationNumber": "testloc1",
                "created": "2021-12-06T06:09:38.762Z",
                "updated": "2021-12-06T06:09:16.076Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test2",
        "logo": "test2.jpg",
        "location": [
            {
                "id": "123",
                "locationNumber": "testloc2",
                "created": "2021-12-06T06:09:38.762Z",
                "updated": "2021-12-06T06:08:50.607Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "test3",
        "logo": "test3.png",
        "location": []
    }
]
```

Error is thrown in this section

```
child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _shopService.fetch(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Shop>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final content = snapshot.data!;
                return gridViewBuild(content);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              }
```

**UPDATE:** I've done some more debugging and I see some stack trace errors

`return jsonResponse.map((item) => new Shop.fromJson(item)).toList();`

Below is the shop.g.dart file from freeze generated where I can see the stack trace error starts.

```
_$_Shop _$$_ShopFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$_Shop(
      id: json['id'] as int?,
      name: json['name'] as String?,
      logo: json['logo'] as String?,
      location: json['location'] == null
          ? null
          : location.fromJson(json['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$$_ShopToJson(_$_Shop instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      'id': instance.id,
      'name': instance.name,
      'logo': instance.logo,
      'location': instance.location,
    };
```

This is the line where error starts:

```
: location.fromJson(json['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
```

Additionlly for completeness this is the location model which is also freeze generaeted.

```
@freezed
class Location with _$Location {
  factory Location({
      String? id,
      @JsonKey(name: 'locationNumber')String? number,
      @JsonKey(name: 'created') String? createdAt,
      @JsonKey(name: 'updated') String? updatedAt,
      String? shop}) = _Location;

  factory Location.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LocationFromJson(json);

  static Location fromJsonModel(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Location.fromJson(json);
}
```

Comment: Which particular line throws that error?

Comment: @RichardHeap Just updated, it is thrown in the builder section in the Future builder, snapshot.hasError

Comment: are you super sure the json response looks like you show? Have you printed the raw response? It looks to me like there is where the error lies

Comment: What happens if you add `print(snapshot.data!.runtimeType);`

Comment: @h8moss I've updated the Json to reflect what it returns from postman, previously i copied the prisma response.

Comment: @RichardHeap I am getting null when i run `print(snapshot.data!.runtimeType);`. I am assuming it is null because of the specified error but i just don't know where to fix this.

Comment: I know it has the same result but maybe its worth trying `List<Shop>.from(jsonResponse.map((item) => Shop.fromJson(item)))`

Comment: I think the problem is when you try to parse `location`. There is double nested `List` on the location's `json` to get `key` and 'value'. This is your location json value `"location":[
         [
            {
            "id": "123",
            "locationNumber": "location2",
            "created": "2021-12-06T06:09:38.762Z",
            "updated": "2021-12-06T06:09:16.076Z"
            }
         ]
      ]`

Comment: You can change your location json structure or change your code to reach location json object.

Comment: Can you show your 'Location' class?

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Thanks for pointing out the JSON it was just a copy and paste error as I was showing the prisma output earlier and just updated the location manually as it was just showing "Object". I can confirm that response is correct. I've also shared the Location details in the post.

Comment: Can you change your `Location? location` on `Shop` class as a List like `List<Location>`?. In your json response the location has list value type.

Comment: CMIIW, this line `: location.fromJson(json['location'] as Map<String, dynamic>),` caused an error because `json['location']` value is `List` type and can't be parsed as `Map<String,dynamic>`.

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Thank you! That was exactly the problem, `Location` to `List<Location>`  and regenerated the freeze files. It is working now!